# Using the module pattern with multiple modules, how can an event listener in one module use a callback from another module?

Tags: inheritance, design-patterns, module, iife

For example

```
const Foo = (function () {
   const something = [];
   const method1 = function(){
      bar.addEventListener("click", method2); //how can I access this method from Foo2??
    };
  return {method1};
})();

const Foo2 = (function () {
    const {method1} = Foo(???); //the example ive found that was remotely close
    const somethingElse = 10;
    const method2 = function(){
       //do something
    };
   return {method2};
})();
```

In the one example I could find they used object destructuring and set it equal to the other module I want to inherit that one specific function from.  I tried to implement this, but it told me `Foo` wasn't a function, or I was trying to access it without initialization.

In their example they had a variable in the parentheses in `Foo` but applying it to my project idk what to put in the parenthesis, everything I tried was an error, even empty parentheses.  Also, I don't know what to put in front of the callback function name in the event listener even if this did work. I've tried `bar.addEventListener("click", Foo2.method2);` and `bar.addEventListener("click", Foo2.method2());`

I've seen this question asked different ways with several different answers but to be honest the explanations are just above my level of understanding. The object destructuring makes the most sense to me but it still didn't work, so I don't know what to do.

I understand prototypal inheritance and being able to say `Foo.prototype.someFunction` to be able to use the methods inside `Foo`, but whats the "factory function/module pattern" equivalent of accomplishing this?

Not even just the event, just how can these two modules connect with each other? Is the syntax wrong, or is it not possible? I just want something to go by an example....something. The assignment requires we use factory functions and the module pattern, there's just not any resources on it that I can find that go behind simply how to turn a regular function into a module, nothing on how to work with multiple modules once you have them for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to explain why this doesn't work than it is to explain what you should do, since honestly this is a bizarre approach.

The function inside `Foo` is immediately invoked. The value that gets assigned to `Foo` is is not a function -- it's the returned value of the function, which is an object with property `method1`.

Inside of `Foo2` you can access the value of the variable `Foo` using `const {method1} = Foo;`.  But you cannot access `Foo2` inside of `Foo` because the function is invoked **immediately**, which means that the you are trying to access `Foo2` before it has been defined.  You can't simply re-order your code because you have a circular dependency between `Foo` and `Foo2`.

In short, **it is not possible to do this with IIFEs**.

---

So don't invoke your functions immediately.  `Foo` can be a factory that takes some arguments and returns an object with `method1`, and the same for `Foo2`

If you are doing that, then you can have multiple distinct instances of foo objects.  For example, `const a = Foo2(5); const b = Foo2(10);`.  It's hard for me to know the best way to design this without knowing the actual goals.

If you *need* this sort of cyclical behavior where both 1 and 2 reference each other then it's hard.  You probably need/want one of your foo factories to take an instance of the other factory as one of its arguments. And you probably need/want to make use of the `this` value of the function.  It's going to be a mess.

If it's a one-directional relationship then it's a lot easier.

Here we create a `Foo2` instance and pass it to `Foo`:

```js
const bar = document.getElementById('bar');

// takes a Foo2 instance as an argument
const Foo = function (foo2Instance) {
    const something = [];
    const method1 = function() {
        bar.addEventListener("click", foo2Instance.method2);
    };
    return {method1};
}

// takes a number as an argument
const Foo2 = function (somethingElse) {
    const method2 = function() {
        alert(somethingElse);
    };
    return {method2};
}

const myFoo2 = Foo2(10);
const myFoo = Foo(myFoo2);
myFoo.method1();
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="bar">Click Me</div>
</body>
```

Here `Foo` is responsible for creating its own internal `Foo2` instance.  Counters "A" and "B" are totally separate and clicking one won't increment the other.  That's because every `Foo` instance has it's own `Foo2` instance.

```js
const Foo = function (counterId) {
    const bar = document.getElementById(counterId);
    const foo2Instance = Foo2();
    const method1 = function() {
        bar.addEventListener("click", foo2Instance.method2);
    };
    return {method1};
}

const Foo2 = function () {
    let count = 0
    const method2 = function() {
       count++;
       console.log(`count is ${count}`);
    };
    return {method2};
}

const counterA = Foo("a");
counterA.method1();
const counterB = Foo("b");
counterB.method1();
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="a">Counter A</div>
  <div id="b">Counter B</div>
</body>
```